# Deploy a Ninjaframework application on openshift

Tags: maven, openshift, ninjaframework

Apologies for the vagueness of this question.

Is it possible or, how can a ninjaframework application be deployed on Openshift.

Basically, I have a Ninjaframework application running locally in superdev mode. I can even build a war file. However, when I push it to an Openshift git repository it simply doesn't work. Specifically, I get a vague "Oops. That's an internal server error and all we know." page when I try to access the site. 
TBH, I'm not surprised. I need to somehow specify to Openshift how to build the application. I'm hoping this can be done by some Maven configurations etc. but I haven't the faintest idea how?

Any help or pointers very much appreciated.

Comment: Try checking the logs with `$ rhc tail` and post back the error here.

Comment: We need the logs in order to answer the question... Ninja will tell you what's wrong... :)

Answer (score -1):

Yep, cool, thanks guys. I'm afraid i was so clueless on how to do this that logs would only tell me what I already knew; that simply git committing a NinjaFramework application configured to build as a fat jar (by default per the archetype) was never going to work in a Tomcat application server. Apologies if that didn't come across in the question.

I expected some elaborate Maven stuff would be required but luckily I was wrong. It turns out that a simple Maven change was all that was required to have the application deployable in OpenShift (Tomcat 7).

I've outlined the steps here in tutorial form: http://outbottle.com/deploying-a-ninjaframework-application-on-openshift/